# Removing matching ID of 2 Eloquent collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this in the database:

```
item: id
item_propiety_list: id
found_item_propieties: item_id, item_propiety_list_id
```

So for each `$item` I get a collection of `found_item_propieties`. If such propieties are not found, nothing is stored in `found_item_propieties`

I want to get an eloquent collection of the ***NOT FOUND*** `item_propiety_list`.

I already do this with SQL, but there is surely some way to do this in Eloquent.

Any advice?

Comment: If you just want a collection, you cloud use `collect($something)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) collection method. If it's a standard Eloquent collection, this should work:

```
$notFound = $collection->where('found_item_properties', null);
```

**Update**

You can use `filter()`:

```
$notFound = $collection->filter(function($i) {
    return empty($i->found_item_properties);
});
```

Comment: Surely it has been my fault not explaining it well enough. If the propety is not found, no entry is created. I only have the found propieties entries in the database, and need to get the not found propieties.